# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict' in Chaquopy with tf.keras.models.load_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, predict, chaquopy

Presented module is part of an Android Studio project. I'm building app for age and gender detection. I tested this module and loading keras model in Google Colab and VS Code and everything works perfectly there. Module isnt finished yet so thats why picture is imported statically etc. h5 and pb saved model exist in given directory and spelling is correct. Please help.

build.gradle:

```
python {
        buildPython "C:/Windows/py.exe", "-3.8"
        pip{
            install "Keras-Applications"
            install "numpy"
            install "Pillow"
            install "opencv-python"
            install "tensorflow"
            install "dlib"
            install "face-cropper"
            install "keras==2.3.0"
        }
    }
```

age_and_gender_detection.py:

```
    
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from face_cropper import crop
from os.path import dirname, join
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

def main(slika):

    loaded_model=None
    cropped_image=None

    try:
        #1.tryout
        dir1 = join(dirname(__file__), "age_and_gender_3_after.h5")
        loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(dir1)

        #2.tryout
        #dir2 = join(dirname(__file__), "saved_model.pb")
        #loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load(dir2)

        #3.tryout
        #model = VGG16()
        print(loaded_model.summary())

        #print(list(loaded.signatures.keys()))  # ["serving_default"]
        #loaded_model.summary()
        print('Model loaded successfully')

    except:
        print('Error while loading model')


    print('tu sam2')
    print('modell: ', loaded_model)
    img_path = join(dirname(__file__), "marin.jpg")

    #paket face-cropper
    cropped_image = crop(
        image_path = img_path,
    )


    if cropped_image==None:
        raise Exception('Image format unknown')

    else:
        #PIL format u cv2
        imcv = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(cropped_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        #podesavanje u prikladan format za fittanje na model
        img_resized = cv2.resize(imcv,(48,48))
        image = cv2.cvtColor(img_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image_test=image/255

        prediction = loaded_model.predict(np.array([image_test]))

        gender_f=['Male','Female']
        age=int(np.round(prediction[1][0]))
        gender=int(np.round(prediction[0][0]))

        print("Predicted Age: "+ str(age))
        print("Predicted Gender: "+ gender_f[gender])

    return "test123"
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.facefun, PID: 6639
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'
        at <python>.age_and_gender_detection.main(age_and_gender_detection.py:56)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:380)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callAttrThrowsNative(chaquopy_java.pyx:352)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrowsNative(Native Method)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrows(PyObject.java:232)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:221)
        at com.example.facefun.UploadPhoto.LaunchResultPage(UploadPhoto.java:143)
```

Comment: It looks like the model is failing to load, but you're ignoring the exception and continuing regardless. Remove the exception handler and run the code again, and then you'll see what the root cause of the crash was.

Comment: "h5 and pb saved model exist in given directory" -- do you mean the same directory as the Python file?

Comment: @mhsmith I removed try-except block and then this error showed up: "ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional". I solved that by downgrading Keras to 2.3.0 and Tensorflow to 2.2.0 in Google Colab and created new h5 save file. Now everything works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mhsmith One more question, Im sending np.ndarray from python script to java and recieving it as: int[][][] image_arr = py_obj.callAttr("main", upload_image).toJava(int[][][].class); ... and it doesnt work, what am I doing wrong? Dont know how to convert it to something that Java accepts

Comment: What are the shape and dtype of the ndarray, and what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?